# Why doesn't the token for the node title work?

Tags: 8, nodes, comments, tokens, message-subscribe

In Drupal 8, I activated the Message module and the Message Example sub-module.

These are the fields I added to the template to create a message when a new comment is created.

> [image]

This is the content of the message.

> 1) [message:node-title]
>   2) [message:field_node_reference:entity:title]

These are the tokens that are listed as available.

> [image]

`[message:node-title]` is replaced from the title of the parent node, but `[message:field_node_reference:entity:title]` is not replaced. Why?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[message:field_node_reference:entity:title]` is not replaced with the node title because, for a *example_create_comment* message template, the *field_node_reference* field doesn't contain any valid node reference.

In fact, the *Message example* module uses the following code to return the value of the `[message:node-title]` token. (See [message_example_tokens()](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/message/tree/modules/message_example/message_example.tokens.inc?h=8.x-1.x#n64).)

```
    case 'node-title':
      if ($message->bundle() == 'example_create_comment') {
        $replacements[$original] = $message->field_comment_reference->entity->getCommentedEntity()->label();
      }
      else {
        $replacements[$original] = $message->field_node_reference->get(0)->entity->label();
      }
      break;
```

When the message bundle (the message template) is *example_create_comment*, it gets the node title using the *field_comment_reference* field (`$message->field_comment_reference->entity->getCommentedEntity()->label()`), not the *field_node_reference* field that is used for the other message templates.

The `[message:field_node_reference:entity:title]` token is added from the Token module, which adds a token for each field a content entity has. (*Message* is a content entity, and *Message template* is its bundle.) The Token module doesn't know if there is another field to use when the *field_node_reference* field doesn't contain any valid reference, so the token is not replaced.

If you want to get the node title in any case, you need to use the `[message:node-title]` token.